# On drawing a line in canvas, it turns into angle. How to solve this using jquery?

Tags: jquery, canvas

I want to draw line in canvas but always at the end of the line it turns into an angle. How to overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance..

Here is my code..

```
 var sigCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasSignature");
         var context = sigCanvas.getContext("2d");
         context.strokeStyle = 'black';
         context.lineWidth = 20;
         var img = new Image();
         var a = document.getElementById("hidVal").value;
         img.src = a;
         img.onload = function(){
              context.drawImage(img,0,0);
         }
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like you're drawing a line at all. It looks like you're using an image. Could you perhaps make a fiddle (www.jsfiddle.net) that shows the effect that you're mentioning? Also, make sure that you put `img.src = a;` **after** the `img.onload`-function.

Comment: @Niddro You are correct. I am using image as background. On setting a different image on load it gives me such error.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what the issue it. Please edit your question above to add more information. You're speaking of a line but no code for drawing a line is visible.